# On Android 7, when using a TTS engine, would power use show for the engine itself or the app using it?

Tags: battery-life, text-to-speech

For example, would power use be attributed to a navigation app or Pico?

Answer (score 0):

Did a test. You can clearly see use on the engine itself.